# load html template on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

have main html template and sub html template.

```
<button id="btn">Click Me...</button>
```

Main HTML:

```
<div id="main">
 <label>Main</label>
</div>
```

Sub HTML:

```
<label>sub</label>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#main").load("main.html");


        });
```

Scenario trying to achieve is I have a common button in all the pages. In default page i.e. Main.html I will show its label. once on click of the button I want to replace the label of main.html with sub.html, Again on click of the button I need to toggle it with the default label.

Can anyone help me out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

i think this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcd7N/1/) is what the OP wants to achieve

loading the html files alternatively :

```
var loadMain = true;
var loadSub = false;
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    if(loadMain){
            $("#main").load("main.html");
        alert("HERE");
            loadSub = true;
            loadMain = false;
    }else{
         $("#main").load("sub.html");
        alert("THERE");
            loadMain = true;
            loadSub = false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change label text with jquery:
Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(e) {

            $("#main").load("main.html");

        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "Main"){
            $("#expanderSign").html("sub")
        }
        else {
            $("#expanderSign").text("Main")
        }

        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wcd7N/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with your code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#main").load("/echo/html/", {html: "<label>sub</label>"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnnhg/2/

The only difference with yours is you don't need that data argument, you use a file. Something else is wrong, like adding the onclick before the button is ready.